# Is there any way to make IDA permanently save recently used files in a list?

Tags: ida, ida-plugin

I usually work with two or three IDBs open at the same time which are linked between themselves (basically the main .exe, and DLLs it loads).

However, every now and then I open different files to take a look, and my "recently used IDBs" quickly gets filled up and the IDBs I work with disappear.

Is there any way I can make IDA stick those IDBs at the top of the "recently opened files" so I can access them easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're on Windows, you could write a script that regularly restores `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Hex-Rays\IDA\History`.

On Linux or Mac OS, I'm sure there's something similar than can be easily restored via a simple script.

Comment: I am on Windows, yes. Can I somehow make an IDC script that runs the registry script each time I load IDA?

Comment: Yes, with [`Exec()`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/198.shtml). However, by the time it's executed IDA will likely already have read the registry info. Why not replace your IDA shortcut in Windows with a batch file that restores the registry entries and then runs IDA?

Comment: Could be. What if I make a plugin using IDA's SDK? Would that get loaded before?